# Xcode not recognising const member function as const

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, const-correctness, function-qualifier

I have a simple fraction class that I'm working on and I've been overloading various operators and they all work apart from my division operator.  For some reason even though it's marked as a const method like all the other operators that return a new Frac and is near identical to the * operator Xcode complains **Candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Frac', but method is not marked const**.  Am I missing something hear or is Xcode not telling me to do what I've already done?

```
Frac operator/(const Frac &r2) const
{
    return this->isRational && r2.isRational ? Frac(this->numerator * r2.denominator, this->denominator * r2.numerator) : Frac(this->floatRatio / r2.floatRatio);
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve], including the full error message and relevant parts of `Frac` class.

Comment: When I extract the minimum parts everything works so I'm unsure what to share.